# Palavra para local, ou utensílio, onde/em que se mistura muita coisa

Tags: expressões, palavra-para-ideia

Existe alguma palavra em português que designe um local, ou utensílio, onde se misture muita coisa?

Por exemplo, hoje numa conversa, tive necessidade de uma palavra assim para caracterizar uma área de conhecimento em que se misturam muitas outras.

Pensei em 'chafurdeira' ou 'mestiça', mas nenhum dos adjectivos me pareceu muito correcto...

Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda.

Comment: Quem sabe, híbrido(a)?

Comment: na música ou cozinha fala-se de _fusão_. Na ciência de estudos multidisciplinares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para "área do conhecimento em que se misturam muitas outras", uma palavra frequentemente usada é `multidisciplinar`.

Para um local, ou utensílio, há a palavra `multiuso` (ou [multiúso(s)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/multi%C3%BAsos)).

Para uma ferramenta, ou para uma pessoa, `versátil` às vezes seria uma boa opção. A palavra `polivalente` poderia ser uma alternativa, mas creio ser pouco usada.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Creio que a palavra multidisciplinar é melhor candidata. No entanto, que palavra podemos usar quando a área de conhecimento é na mesma área/disciplina mas com diferentes 'subáreas' ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Estive pensando sobre sua pergunta, e nada me ocorre, talvez em parte porque não entendo exatamente a situação. Você se refere à uma área como a medicina, que se divide em uma infinidade de especializações?

Comment: É semelhante a esse exemplo de medicina... Por exemplo, refiro-me a uma área da matemática que envolve muita estatística, probabilidade, equações diferenciais parciais, e optimização

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Parece teoria de controle. Não me ocorre nada melhor que "multidisciplinar", dado que ele pode ser usado tanto para múltiplas áreas quanto para múltiplas subáreas.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado ;)